# How to hoist state into parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have presentation and container components. Presentation component use local state. I want to remove local state to parent component. This is necessary so that the presentation component has no logic. Please help me

Page1.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Page1(props) {
  let textareaRef = React.createRef();
  
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    presentText: '',
  });

  function textareaSet() {
    props.setAppTextCreator(textareaRef.current.value);
    textareaRef.current.value = '';
  }

  function textareaChange() {
    setState({...state, presentText: textareaRef.current.value})
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <textarea 
          ref={ textareaRef }
          onChange={ textareaChange }>
        </textarea>
        <button onClick={ textareaSet }>send</button>
        <div>present: { state.presentText }</div>
        <div>memorized: { props.text }</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page1;
```

Page1smart.jsx:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { setAppTextCreator } from '../../redux/appReducer';

import Page1 from './Page1';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    text: state.appReducer.appText,
    presentText: state.presentText
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setAppTextCreator })(Page1);
```

Comment: which is the Presentation component and which is the parent component  here ?

Comment: Do you happen to know about [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)?

Comment: ...and, by the way, what you need has nothing to do with *hoisting*

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov, Your example doesn't use the function connect. In my example, the container component does not contain a class

Comment: Since you've not shared any "parent" component and it appears you are passing in the state and update functions via redux `connect` HOC, "Lifting State Up" isn't the correct pattern. Provided a solution below assuming you are just wanting to eliminate local component state in `Page1`. FYI, "presentation" containers *can* have their own local state if the state is only relevant to *that* component while it's mounted, that is quite alright.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question/issue correctly, you are simply wanting to remove the local component state from `Page1` and pass in the state from redux.

1. Remove the textarea `onChange` handler, you will access the current value later.
2. Render `presentText` passed from props.
3. Use the `useRef` react hook and declare `textareaRef` const as it isn't reassigned during render.

Page1

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

function Page1({ presentText, setAppTextCreator, text }) {
  const textareaRef = useRef();
  
  function textareaSet() {
    setAppTextCreator(textareaRef.current.value);
    textareaRef.current.value = '';
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <textarea ref={textareaRef} />
        <button onClick={textareaSet}>send</button>
        <div>present: {presentText}</div>
        <div>memorized: {text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```